# How to config pip.conf for python2 and python3

Tags: python, pip

When I run `pip3 list`, I got the message `DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.`. When I modified my `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` and added

```sh
[list]
    --format=columns
```

to the `pip.conf`. However, I got another wrong message when I run `pip2 list`:

```sh
Configuration file could not be loaded.
File contains parsing errors: /data/home/user00/.pip/pip.conf
        [line  2]: '    --format=columns\n'
```

How should I config the pip.conf to satisfied both `pip2` and `pip3` to run?

Answer (score 2):

`pip3 list` error message:

> DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use ***--format=(legacy|columns)*** (or ***define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf*** under the [list] section) to disable this warning.

In your config file you need to use

```
[list]
format=columns
```

or add `--format=columns` to `pip3 list` command

```sh
pip3 list --format=columns
```

Comment: I see, but my question is this:
```bash
$ pip list
Configuration file could not be loaded.
File contains parsing errors: /data/home/modnar/.pip/pip.conf
        [line  2]: '    format=columns\n'
```

Comment: Remove that indentation and check

Comment: Wow, fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, if I want to make pip2 use `--format legacy` while pip3 use `--format columns`, how should I change the `pip.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

**Just upgrade your pip:**

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools


pip install pip --upgrade
```